# Carousal slider image is not visible properly in flutter image getting bulrred

Tags: flutter, slider, carousel

here is the code
how can I achieve a proper visible image
please provide solution
I tried aspect ratio and proper height width but it did not work in my case

```
 CarouselSlider(
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                  onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                          setState(() {
                          _current = index;
                          });},

                    autoPlayAnimationDuration:Duration(seconds: 1),
                    autoPlayCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
                    aspectRatio: 16/9,
                    viewportFraction: 0.8,
                    enlargeFactor: 0.3,

                    autoPlay: true,
                    height: 150,



                    enlargeCenterPage: true,
                  ),
                  items: banner_images.map((index) {
                    return PageView(
                      controller: controller,
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      children: [
                        Container(


                          padding : EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color:Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(index.bannerImage.toString(),
                                ),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              )
                            ),
                         //  child: Image.network(index.bannerImage.toString(),

                           ),

                      ]
                    );
                  }).toList(),
```